# MySql Query for fetching first record of every hour in Table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with thousands of records of meter data. Every smart meter will keep on sending data. I want to fetch only the first record of every hour, for each meter.

Here is an example of data in the table:

```
meter_id    meter_time
300020013   2014-03-01 02:06:06
300020013   2014-03-01 02:06:06
300020013   2014-03-01 02:06:06
300020013   2014-03-01 02:06:06
300020013   2014-03-01 02:06:06
300020013   2014-03-01 02:06:06
300020007   2014-02-19 16:05:31
300020007   2014-02-19 16:05:31
300020007   2014-02-19 16:05:31
300020007   2014-02-19 16:05:31
300020007   2014-02-19 16:05:31
300020007   2014-02-19 16:05:31
```

Comment: Can you post any code that you have tried to do this? Also, please post the layout of your table such as field names and types

Comment: meter_id meter_time
300020013 2014-03-01 02:06:06
300020013 2014-03-01 02:06:06
300020013 2014-03-01 02:06:06
300020013 2014-03-01 02:06:06
300020013 2014-03-01 02:06:06
300020013 2014-03-01 02:06:06
300020007 2014-02-19 16:05:31
300020007 2014-02-19 16:05:31
300020007 2014-02-19 16:05:31
300020007 2014-02-19 16:05:31
300020007 2014-02-19 16:05:31
300020007 2014-02-19 16:05:31

Answer (score -2):

This should be your solution:

```
SELECT HOURS, RECORDS FROM HOURS GROUP BY HOURS
```

[Here is the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbd6e/1).

Comment: Then can you please elaborate your problem with some demo data.

Comment: It's not my problem, it's from my understanding of the users problem.

Comment: Then as per my understandings the solution is absolutely correct. U must prefer them at least.

Comment: @ankit there is no problem in existence for which this should be considered the correct answer